# Generated button not working -JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

A generated button using Jquery's method is not working. The Id of the generated button is gpaCalculate. I have tried with both click and on methods but its not working. I don't know where I went wrong.
Here is a link to my whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/4rxq49ko/

```
 $(document).on("click","#gpaCalculate",function(){
    displayDetails();
})
```

**generated button JQuery**

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function () {
      myval = parseInt($(this).val());
      $(".tableAppend").empty();

      $(".tableAppend").append('<tr><th></th><th>Courses</th><th>Credit Hours</th><th>Grade</th></tr>');
      $(".tableAppend").append('<tr><input type="submit" name="calculateGPA" value="Click Me" id="calculateGPA" /></tr>');
      for (var i = 1 ; i <= myval ; i++) {
          $(".tableAppend").append('<tr><td>' + (i) + '.</td><td><input name="courseTextBox' + i + '" type="text" id="courseTextBox' + i + '"></td>' +
              '<td><input name="creditTextBox' + i + '" type="text" id="creditTextBox' + i + '">  </td>' +
              '<td><select id="gradeSelect' + i + '">' +
                                   '<option value ="A">A</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="A-">A-</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="B+">B+</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="B">B</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="B-">B-</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="C+">C+</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="C">C</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="C-">C-</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="D">D</option>' +
                                   '<option value ="F">F</option>' +
                 '</select></td>');

      }
      $(".tableAppend").append('<tr><td></td><td><button type="submit" id="gpaCalculate" >Calculate GPA</button></td>');
  });
```

Comment: Where is your jquery which is registered on button?

Comment: you are using server side dropdown control. In jquery the selector for the the dropdown is supposed to be $('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientId%>')

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$("#gpaCalculate").onclick(function () {
    displayDetails();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function () {
myval = parseInt($(this).val());
$(".tableAppend").empty();

$(".tableAppend").append('<tr><th></th><th>Courses</th><th>Credit Hours</th><th>Grade</th></tr>');
$(".tableAppend").append('<tr><input type="submit" name="calculateGPA" value="Click Me" id="calculateGPA" /></tr>');
for (var i = 1 ; i <= myval ; i++) {
$(".tableAppend").append('<tr><td>' + i + '.</td><td><input name="courseTextBox' + i + '" type="text" id="courseTextBox' + i + '"></td>' +
  '<td><input name="creditTextBox' + i + '" type="text" id="creditTextBox' + i + '">  </td>' +
  '<td><select id="gradeSelect' + i + '">' +
     '<option value ="A">A</option>' +
     '<option value ="A-">A-</option>' +
     '<option value ="B+">B+</option>' +
     '<option value ="B">B</option>' +
     '<option value ="B-">B-</option>' +
     '<option value ="C+">C+</option>' +
     '<option value ="C">C</option>' +
     '<option value ="C-">C-</option>' +
     '<option value ="D">D</option>' +
     '<option value ="F">F</option>' +
     '</select></td>');

}
$(".tableAppend").append('<tr><td></td><td><button type="submit" id="gpaCalculate">Calculate GPA</button></td>');
$("#gpaCalculate").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
displayDetails();
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this method a try.

```
$( "#gpaCalculate" ).live( "click", function() {
    alert( "Goodbye!" );
});
```